# X.Lookup fails in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Good morning,

trying to create a x.lookup using data from a .txt file, copied to excel, using the text to column function to sort the data. small example below :

2.1 Dig. Oil Meter - Max. Oil                                        |90       |%
2.2 Dig. Oil Meter - Min. Oil %                                                  |10       |%
2.3 Dig. Oil Meter - Min. Refill Lvl                                             |27       |0,1 L
2.4 Dig. Oil Meter - Error Low %                                                 |0        |%

This is a small snippet from a report that is generated to visualize the parameter settings of an old display.

and in excel this looks like :
[image: view in excel]

the value that i need is in colom B.

Now, in an Excel file i can create a parameter file to program a new display, for that i need the parameter settings from the report as mentioned above, this is done by hand, so read the .txt on the left screen, while filling in the values in the excel on the right screen.

I am trying to automate this, by copying/importing the data into the excel document(using std excel import or VBA) and then doing a x.lookup to autofill the values but that gives me an error : #N/B - I think i found the reason for this is that the DATA that is being copied/imported from .txt contains spaces at the end - So at the end of % sign in the example above and before the | there are spaces which the Xlookup function does not ignore (i notice that this post does not resembles the view in the .txt file so i added an image (2) to the post)
[image: empty spaces]

Anybody an idea on how to remove just those spaces at the end?

Comment: Please post your formula which doesn't work, without seeing it, it's really difficult to correct it.

Comment: Tnx for responding, however i just answered my own question, google is great, but you do have the right questions, which should be : How to remove trailing spaces in excel, and the answer to remove those is quite simple : by using the =TRIM function. by using that now the xlookup works flawlessly.

Comment: @DietBos Go ahead and add that as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Tnx for responding, however i just answered my own question, google is great, but you do have the right questions, which should be : How to remove trailing spaces in excel, and the answer to remove those is quite simple : by using the =TRIM function. by using that now the xlookup works flawlessly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).